# Is it possible to send the form details through mail using java mail api in android?

Tags: java, android, email

i have written a program which has a form consisting of name , phone no and email and a submit button to send the above details to a mail address ,
i have also tried using intent and it works fine but i dont want to use intent as i want the user to stay inside the application and not go outside the application.
So i got the code for java mail api , and also receiving messages in my mail when i click on submit button , but is it possible to also send the form details with it ?

```
"Name : " + eName.getText().toString() + '\n' + "Email ID : " + eEmail.getText().toString() + '\n' + "Contact No : " +ePhone.getText().toString() + '\n' + "Message : " + eMessage.getText().toString()
```

i want to send the above data inside this

```
    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(

        "email-address",
        "password");
        // sender.addAttachment(Environment
        // .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        // + "/image.jpg");

        sender.sendMail("Test mail", "Body message",
                        "fsfas@gdf.com",// From
                        "fasfsdf@gdfs.com");// To

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Please check the internet connection",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   }
```

Is it possible ?
If yes then need some help please
Thanking You

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla Java Mail API isn't available in Android.
Here are some available solutions :

1. Send those information to a webservice of yours which will send the mail on its own
2. Use the Gmail API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview
3. Send the mail using a SMTP server (not tested)